# Dynamic HTML5 Datalist

Tags: jquery, html, for-loop, append, html-datalist

So I am having a bit of an issue getting my HTML5 Datalist to populate dynamically from a javascript array that is being populated from values of a key of an object that is being populated via rows in a MySQL database. Phew!

MySQL Database => Table => Rows => JSON => Javascript Objects => "firstname" & "lastname" key => Array of first names => Datalist Options.

I successfully created the Array of names:

```
var nameArray = ["Rick Bross","Madison Smith","Jack Johnson"]; //Example of my array
```

And set up a loop to .append them to the datalist:

```
for (var i = 0; i < nameArray.length; i++) {
    alert(i + " - " + nameArray[i]); //Works Fine, "0 - Rick Bross", "1 - Madison Smith", etc.
    $('#potentials').append("<option value='" + nameArray[i] + ">"); // Not working.
}
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<input tabindex='1' list="potentials" type="text" placeholder="First &amp; Last Name" id="name" name="name"></input>
<datalist id="potentials">
</datalist>
```

Why this isn't populating?

Comment: +1 for a sscce-compliant question :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I know this answer is late but it might help someone.

`var nameArray = ["Rick Bross","Madison Smith","Jack Johnson"];`

Add options to the datalist.
- "attr" helps if you need an i.d to identify each option.
- "text" is the content to be displayed.

`$.each(nameArray, function(i, item) {
      $("#potentials").append($("<option>").attr('value', i).text(item));
    });`

Answer (score 17):

There was a missing apostrophe, try:

```
$('#potentials').append("<option value='" + nameArray[i] + "'>");
```

Answer (score -6):

Try $("datalist#potentials).append...

Comment: If `$('#potentials')` does not work, including the element type in the selector as `$('datalist#potentials')` will not help.